# find the user entered value or sum the row values

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

i need get the invoice number which has the particular value in price column, if not all the invoice numbers which have the sum value of that particular value in price column ..how to write an sql query for that

i have attached the data of my table
Data

```html
invoice     price
v1         1000      
v2         200       
v3         35        
v4         500       
v5         50        
v6         300       
v7         400
```

expected output :
if(input 500) found =>then found v4

else(sum of(v2,v6)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: I don't understand 'if not all the invoice numbers which have the sum value of that particular value in price column ' - can you clarify please preferably with sample data and expected output.

Comment: added please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all combinations of 1 or two invoices that meet your conditions:

```
select d1.invoice, d1.price,
       (case when d2.invoice <> d1.invoice then d2.invoice end) as invoice2,
       (case when d2.invoice <> d1.invoice then d2.price end) as price2
from data d1 left join
     data d2
     on d1.invoice <= d2.invoice
where (d1.price = 500 and d2.invoice = d1.invoice) or
      (d1.price + d2.price) = 500
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e3ece57d538061c53c3c8ec4fe2eece) is a db<>fiddle.

If you want larger combinations, add more joins.

Comment: D1 and D2 data are same so left join on the above condition will return all data right.

Comment: I am confused,can you please explain me thanks in advance

Comment: @ABCD . . . I tweaked the query and added a db fiddle.  This is getting individual invoices or pairs that add to the total price you want.

Comment: If I need 100 combination, do I need to add 50 joins ????? Is there any short way

Comment: @ABCD . . . Yes.

Comment: Can you please tell me the short way please

Comment: (1) I think this answers the question that you have asked here.  I've even included a db<>fiddle that demonstrates this.  (2) You can ask another question.  (3) You really cannot use SQL for this purpose.  It requires very expensive processing.

Comment: Ok @Gordon understood